# Values are null in action class struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, action

I have a jsp page as below (ConfigureRate.jsp):

```
<s:form action="modifyrate.action" method="post">
                    <s:textfield label="Country" name="selectedCountry" value="%{#session.selectedCallRates.country}" size="20" disabled="true" />
                    <s:textfield label="Country Code" name="countrycode" value="%{#session.selectedCallRates.countrycode}" size="20" disabled="true"/>
                    <s:textfield label="Call Direction" name="selectedCallType" value="%{#session.selectedCallRates.callType}" disabled="true"/>
                    <s:textfield label="Device Type" name="selectedDeviceType" value="%{#session.selectedCallRates.deviceType}" disabled="true"/>
                    <s:textfield name="rate" key="label.rate" size="20" />
                    <s:submit method="modifyRate" key="Update" align="center" />
                </s:form>
```

And have the setters and getters in the action class for selectedCallType, selectedDeviceType etc .....

Action Code :

```
public class ConfigureRatesAction extends ActionSupport {

private List<CallRates> callRates;
private String selectedCountryRow;
private String selectedCallType;
private String selectedDeviceType;
private String country;
private int countrycode;
private double rate;
private String selectedCountry;
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConfigureRatesAction.class);

public String displayModify() {

    Boolean loggedin = (Boolean) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("loggedin");
    CallRatesDAO callRatesDAO = new CallRatesDAO();

    if (loggedin == null || !loggedin) {
        addActionError(getText("error.loggedin"));
        return "loggedout";
    }

    if (selectedCountryRow == null) {
        callRates =
                callRatesDAO.getCallRates();
        addActionError("Select a row to modify");
        return ERROR;
    }

    CallRates selectedCallRates = buildCallRates(selectedCountryRow);

    if (selectedCallRates == null) {
        callRates = callRatesDAO.getCallRates();
        addActionError("Select a row to modify");
        return ERROR;
    } else {
        ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("selectedCallRates", selectedCallRates);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}

public String modifyRate() {



    Boolean loggedin = (Boolean) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("loggedin");

    if (loggedin == null || !loggedin) {
        addActionError(getText("error.loggedin"));
        return "loggedout";
    }

    CallRatesDAO callRatesDAO = new CallRatesDAO();

    log.info("Values :"+selectedCountry+" "+countrycode+" "+selectedCallType
            +" "+selectedDeviceType+" "+rate);


    if (callRatesDAO.updateRate(selectedCountry, rate, Integer.toString(countrycode),
            selectedCallType, selectedDeviceType)) {
        callRates = callRatesDAO.getCallRates();
        addActionMessage(getText("success.modifyrate"));
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        addActionError(getText("errors.modifyrate"));
        return ERROR;
    }
}

private CallRates buildCallRates(String selectedCountryRow) {

    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(selectedCountryRow, "*");
    CallRates cR = new CallRates();
    int i = 1;

    while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (i == 1) {
            cR.setCountry(token.nextToken());
        } else if (i == 2) {
            cR.setCountrycode(Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()));
        } else if (i == 3) {
            cR.setCallType(token.nextToken());
        } else if (i == 4) {
            cR.setDeviceType(token.nextToken());
        }
        i++;
    }

    return cR;
}

public List<CallRates> getCallRates() {
    return callRates;
}

public void setCallRates(List<CallRates> callRates) {
    this.callRates = callRates;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public int getCountrycode() {
    return countrycode;
}

public void setCountrycode(int countrycode) {
    this.countrycode = countrycode;
}

public double getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(double rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public String getSelectedCallType() {
    return selectedCallType;
}

public void setSelectedCallType(String selectedCallType) {
    this.selectedCallType = selectedCallType;
}

public String getSelectedCountry() {
    return selectedCountry;
}

public void setSelectedCountry(String selectedCountry) {
    this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
}

public String getSelectedCountryRow() {
    return selectedCountryRow;
}

public void setSelectedCountryRow(String selectedCountryRow) {
    this.selectedCountryRow = selectedCountryRow;
}

public String getSelectedDeviceType() {
    return selectedDeviceType;
}

public void setSelectedDeviceType(String selectedDeviceType) {
    this.selectedDeviceType = selectedDeviceType;
}
```

}

struts.xml :

```
  <action name="modifyAction"
            class="com.thrupoint.brg.callrates.configurerates.ConfigureRatesAction" method="displayModify">
        <result name="success">jsp/ConfigureRate.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">jsp/modifyrates.jsp</result>
        <result name="loggedout">jsp/Login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="modifyrate"
            class="com.thrupoint.brg.callrates.configurerates.ConfigureRatesAction" method="modifyRate">
        <result name="success">jsp/modifyrates.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">jsp/ConfigureRate.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">jsp/ConfigureRate.jsp</result>
        <result name="loggedout">jsp/Login.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

When I print the values of these properties in action class, I get null, except rate property which doesn't have value attribute in above jsp form.

Why are other properties are null?

Comment: Post the action code.

Comment: Hi Roman, updated the post with action code above.

Comment: Do you agree with me? Why do you reference `null` session properties, why not to populate bean from session before result, or at least use session scope.

Comment: The session properties are not null and they do get displayed on the page, but after submitting the form the properties are "null" in the modifyRate method.

Comment: `struts.xml` needed, update please.

Comment: Also, the method might return `"loggedout"` when you submit, when your session is timed off.

Comment: Hi Roman, updated the post with struts.xml. Yeah that's fine if the session is timed out and on result loggedout the action will render the login page.

Comment: You should put the logging into the setter and check when the value is populated.

Comment: Thanks for the help Roman, as Nitesh mentioned below, the fields with disabled property set to true won't get submitted. This resolved my problem.

Comment: Next time format the code better, so I'm able to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load that JSP, does those Textfields show any Data or remains Empty.

Secondly, as those Textfields are disabled its value will not be submitted. So, either enable it or take datas from session in the action method.

N.B.: Disabled element never get submitted. If you want nobody to edit those fields, then make them **Readonly** instead of disabling it.

Comment: Ah, that is what I am looking for ...... does disabled fields won't get submitted? Yes the textfields show data that is saved in session. I don't want user to edit those fields that is the reason why I disabled them.

Comment: you welcome, let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: This works a treat. Removed disabled attribute and added readOnly attribute. Thanks again!

Comment: I voting this up for the important point `Disabled element never get submitted`. Thanks